# SPOTIFY API- Grab multiple artists

Tags: python, pandas, api, spotify

I've created a class where i'm able to pull api using my client ID and credential ID.

In This Example - i wrote a function - get_all_artists, this function should allow me to pull multiple artist based on ID. but it gives me a 404 error, is there a better way to create a function to pull multiple artists?

```
class SpotifyAPI(object):
    access_token = None
    access_token_expires = datetime.datetime.now()
    access_token_did_expire = True
    client_id = None
    client_secret = None
    token_url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"

def __init__(self, client_id, client_secret, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.client_id = client_id
    self.client_secret = client_secret

def get_client_credentials(self):
    """
    Returns a base64 encoded string
    """
    client_id = self.client_id
    client_secret = self.client_secret
    if client_secret == None or client_id == None:
        raise Exception("You must set client_id and client_secret")
    client_creds = f"{client_id}:{client_secret}"
    client_creds_b64 = base64.b64encode(client_creds.encode())
    return client_creds_b64.decode()

def get_token_headers(self):
    client_creds_b64 = self.get_client_credentials()
    return {
        "Authorization": f"Basic {client_creds_b64}"
    }

def get_token_data(self):
    return {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials"
    } 

def perform_auth(self):
    token_url = self.token_url
    token_data = self.get_token_data()
    token_headers = self.get_token_headers()
    r = requests.post(token_url, data=token_data, headers=token_headers)
    if r.status_code not in range(200, 299):
        raise Exception("Could not authenticate client.")
        # return False
    data = r.json()
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    access_token = data['access_token']
    expires_in = data['expires_in'] # seconds
    expires = now + datetime.timedelta(seconds=expires_in)
    self.access_token = access_token
    self.access_token_expires = expires
    self.access_token_did_expire = expires < now
    return True

def get_access_token(self):
    token = self.access_token
    expires = self.access_token_expires
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if expires < now:
        self.perform_auth()
        return self.get_access_token()
    elif token == None:
        self.perform_auth()
        return self.get_access_token() 
    return token

def get_resource_header(self):
    access_token = self.get_access_token()
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
    }
    return headers
    
    
def get_resource(self, lookup_id, resource_type='albums', version='v1'):
    endpoint = f"https://api.spotify.com/{version}/{resource_type}/{lookup_id}"
    headers = self.get_resource_header()
    r = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers)
    if r.status_code not in range(200, 299):
        return {}
    return r.json()

def get_album(self, _id):
    return self.get_resource(_id, resource_type='albums')

def get_artist(self, _id):
    return self.get_resource(_id, resource_type='artists')

#get all artists 
def get_all_artists(self, resource_type='artists', version='v1'): 
    endpoint = f"https://api.spotify.com/{version}/{resource_type}/?ids="
    headers = self.get_resource_header() 
    r = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers)
    if r.status_code in range(200, 299): 
        return {} 
    return r.json() 

def base_search(self, query_params): # type
    headers = self.get_resource_header()
    endpoint = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search"
    lookup_url = f"{endpoint}?{query_params}"
    r = requests.get(lookup_url, headers=headers)
    if r.status_code not in range(200, 299):  
        return {}
    return r.json()

def search(self, query=None, operator=None, operator_query=None, search_type='artist' ):
    if query == None:
        raise Exception("A query is required")
    if isinstance(query, dict):
        query = " ".join([f"{k}:{v}" for k,v in query.items()])
    if operator != None and operator_query != None:
        if operator.lower() == "or" or operator.lower() == "not":
            operator = operator.upper()
            if isinstance(operator_query, str):
                query = f"{query} {operator} {operator_query}"
    query_params = urlencode({"q": query, "type": search_type.lower()})
    print(query_params)
    return self.base_search(query_params)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        spotify = SpotifyAPI(client_id, client_secret)
        spotify.perform_auth()
        spotify.get_access_token()
```

I've created a function where i want to pull multiple Artists, but it gives me an error

```
import pandas as pd
import warnings 
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
#normalize the data to get proper form for one artist
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize 


all_artists = spotify.get_all_artists("7LTShHcq1KdTrWeLvWoYed", "64k5e9kV9MdukXjFrR5R37")
df2 = pd.json_normalize(all_artists)
```

I get a 404 error, can someone help?

Comment: 404 Error, Page Not Found, File Not Found, or Server Not Found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404

Answer (score 1):

[https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/{id}](https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/%7Bid%7D)

is only for one artist, you need:

https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists
with the ids as parameters

example: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists?ids=2CIMQHirSU0MQqyYHq0eOx%2C57dN52uHvrHOxijzpIgu3E%2C1vCWHaC5f2uS3yhpwWbIA6"

https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-several-artists/